# Fetch images real-time from dropbox using Meteor.js

Tags: meteor, dropbox

Is it possible to fetch image from dropbox and display it using Meteor.js?

The images does not need to save into a collection. I just need the app to fetch if there's any new images added on the dropbox.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for something that allows you to both upload and download from dropbox you can check out the `cfs:dropbox` package which acts as a module on top of [CollectionFS](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS). However if you are just looking for an api wrapper you can use one of the many dropbox packages on atmosphere: https://atmospherejs.com/?q=dropbox